# Entity Manager doesn't return all elements like inserted

Tags: java, postgresql, entitymanager

I have a problem with the entity manager. I want to insert approximately 4000 objects in one database. After the insert statement I want all elements back for the further processing. Problem is that I just get 1700 objects back.

This is the service:

```
public void addAllElementsToDatabase() {

    System.out.println("### listObjects: " + listObjects.size());

    for (Object object : listObjects) {
        objectDAO.create(object);
        // objectDAO.edit(object);
    }

    System.out.println("### listObjects after: " + objectDAO.findAll().size());
    System.out.println("### count rows: " + objectDAO.count());
}
```

ObjectDAO extends from GenericDAO. GenericDAO looks like:

```
private Class<T> entityClass;

public GenericDAO(Class<T> entityClass) {
    this.entityClass = entityClass;
}

protected abstract EntityManager getEntityManager();

public void create(T entity) {
    getEntityManager().persist(entity);
}

public void edit(T entity) {
    getEntityManager().merge(entity);
}

public int count() {
    javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
    javax.persistence.criteria.Root<T> rt = cq.from(entityClass);
    cq.select(getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().count(rt));
    javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
    return ((Long) q.getSingleResult()).intValue();
}

public List<T> findAll() {
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
        return getEntityManager().createQuery(cq).getResultList();
}
```

Output:

```
INFO: ### listObjects: 4182
INFO: ### listObjects after: 1711
INFO: ### count rows: 4182
```

pgAdmin3 also shows me 4182 rows. If I count the rows with a SQL statement in the console I also get the number 4182, but I don't get all 4182 elementsin a list. It doesn't matter whether I use edit() or create().

I use:

Glassfish: 3.1.2.2

JPA-Provider: EclipseLink 2.5, JPA 2.1

PostgreSQL 9.1

JDK 1.7

How can this be?

Comment: What does it mean _but I don't get all 4182 elementsin a list_?

Answer (score 1):

Problem was the FetchType in my mapping:

```
@JoinFetch(value = JoinFetchType.INNER)
```

I expected that the value cannot be null/ 0, so FetchType.OUTER solved the issue:

```
@JoinFetch(value = JoinFetchType.OUTER)
```